# extract rows from data.frame with only numeric values

Tags: r

To my surprise, I couldn't find this being asked before.

My input data.frame

```
a <- c(1,5.3,3,1,-8,6,-1)
b <- c(4,-2,1.0,"1 2","-","1.2.3","x")
df <- data.frame(a,b)
df
   a     b
1  1     4
2  5.3  -2
3  3     1
4  1   1 2
5 -8     -
6  6 1.2.3
7 -1     x
```

Desired output

```
    a  b
1 1.0  4
2 5.3 -2
3 3.0  1
```

What I came up with

```
df[apply(df, 1, function(r) !any(is.na(as.numeric(r)))) ,]
```

It works but it throws some ugly warnings

```
    a  b
1 1.0  4
2 5.3 -2
3 3.0  1
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Any better idea using R base if possible?

Comment: Is there any reason why your source data frame contains both text and non text data in the same column?

Comment: It's just to avoid wrong input from the user. Note that all values in b are considered as text, but some of them can (and should) be coerced to numeric.

Comment: This may look a bit silly now, but I just realized that
`suppressWarnings( df[apply(df, 1, function(r) !any(is.na(as.numeric(r)))) ,] )`
is probably the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple **base R** solutions using `strtoi` (without warnings)

**rowSums** (all integer)

```
df[ !is.na( rowSums( sapply( df, strtoi ) ) ), ]

  a  b
1 1  4
2 5 -2
3 3  1
```

**complete.cases** (all integer)

```
df[ complete.cases( sapply( df, strtoi ) ), ]

  a  b
1 1  4
2 5 -2
3 3  1
```

**EDIT** after changes (some float)

The next uses double sapply to touch every single value, no vectors. It's important in cases where you have conflicting modes, i.e. ifelse can't decide.

```
df
    a     b
1   1     4
2 5.3    -2
3   3     1
4   1   1 2
5  -8     -
6   6   1.3
7  -1     x
8 2.5 1.2.3

data.frame( na.omit( sapply( df, function(x) 
  sapply( x, function(y) 
    ifelse(grepl("^-?\\d+\\.\\d+$", y), as.numeric(y), strtoi(y)) ) )))

      a    b
1   1.0  4.0
5.3 5.3 -2.0
3   3.0  1.0
6   6.0  1.3
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this solution also removes float numerics. I have edited the input data.frame of my question

Answer (score 2):

**note: edited after you altered your question**

I don't think the warnings are a big problem. They just tell you what you know already; that 4 character values return NA when coerced to numeric.

You could filter the data frame for only positive or negative digit values, then convert to numeric, using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(if_all(everything(), ~ grepl("^-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$", .x))) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.numeric(.x)))
```

Result:

```
    a  b
1 1.0  4
2 5.3 -2
3 3.0  1
```